# SaveChanges vs SaveChangesAsync benchmark: weird results

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, benchmarking

I've written a simple benchmark, maybe it's wrong and gives an unexpected (for me) result... that's why I'm asking you to explain me and even better to correct my example.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startDate = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                InsertEntity(i);
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
            }

            var endDate = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine($"Total elapsed time: {(endDate - startDate).TotalMilliseconds}");
        }

        static void InsertEntity(int i)
        {
            using (var context = new TestContext())
            {
                var entity = new Entity
                {
                    Code = $"Code {i}",
                    Name = $"Name {i}",
                    Description = $"Description {i}"
                };
                context.Entities.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Total elapsed time: 9585ms

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startDate = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                InsertEntity(i).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
            }

            var endDate = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine($"Total elapsed time: {(endDate - startDate).TotalMilliseconds}");
        }

        static async Task InsertEntity(int i)
        {
            using (var context = new TestContext())
            {
                var entity = new Entity
                {
                    Code = $"Code {i}",
                    Name = $"Name {i}",
                    Description = $"Description {i}"
                };
                await context.Entities.AddAsync(entity);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Total elapsed time: 13479ms

I expected the other way around, given that async programming can free threads during I/O bound operations... is this correct? So why it is actually slower?

Comment: The async and await pattern is not a performance feature, its a scalability feature. it has overhead,

Comment: It's not async when you're explicitly blocking the main thread. The longer time is probably because of the overhead of using the TPL.

Comment: You're invoking an async method and waiting on the result. Althought `InsertEntity` calls async methods it awaits them, so it is outwardly synchronous in this regard. Also, the async/await state machine will add complexity to the method, which will affect the performance.

Comment: So why the recommended approach is to always use async/await when possibile? Only for scalability?

Comment: It's partly for scalability, but also to run things asynchronously in the "background" when their results are not immediately needed. A simple example would be `var task = MyFuncAsync(); MyOtherFunc(); await task;`. In this case MyFuncAsync is started, then MyOtherFunc is processed and finally it waits until MyFuncAsync finishes; thus both functions run alongside each other, which would make your code more performant.